# MaybeT applicative instance without monad constraint for the outer monad

Tags: javascript, haskell, monad-transformers, applicative

I am implementing the monad transformer of the `Maybe` (aka `Option`) type in Javascript (please note that I use type-dictionary passing):

```js
const optOfT = of => x =>
  of(optOf(x));

const optMapT = map => f => ttx =>
  map(optMap(f)) (ttx);

const optApT = chain => ttf => ttx =>
  chain(tf =>
    chain(tx =>
      optAp(tf) (tx)) (ttx)) (ttf);

const optChainT = chain => fm => mmx =>
  chain(mx =>
    optChain(fm) (mx)) (mmx);
```

(map ~ `<$>`, ap ~ `<*>`, chain ~ `=<<`, of = pure/return)

While this code works I wonder if I can implement `optApT` without the monad constraint for the outer monad. I stumbled upon this Haskell example:

```hs
(<<**>>) :: (Applicative a, Applicative b) => a (b (s -> t)) -> a (b s) -> a (b t)
abf <<**>> abs = pure (<*>) <*> abf <*> abs
```

This seems exactly what I want, but I can't recognize the evaluation order of `pure (<*>) <*> abf <*> abs` and which `<*>` operator belongs to which applicative layer:

```js
const optApT = (ap, of) => ttf => ttx =>
  ...?
```

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this helps...

Here are the types associated with the various type-class functions:

```
abf <<**>> abs = pure (<*>) <*> abf <*> abs
                  (4)  (3)  (2)     (1)

(1), (2): the `ap` for type a
(3): the `ap` for type b
(4): the `pure` for type a
```

And the evaluation order is:

```
(pure (<*>)) <*> abf <*> abs
```

Comment: I was that close. Here is the working code: `(ap, of) => ttf => ttx => ap(ap(of(optAp)) (ttf)) (ttx)`. Thank you!

Comment: `optApT` can actually be simplified to `(map, ap) => ttf => ttx => ap(map(optAp) (ttf)) (ttx)`. And with eta reduction to `(map, ap) => ttf => ap(map(optAp) (ttf))` FP is amazing!